# Angular: set Content-Type per query

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, content-type, angular-services

I need to perform one query with `Content-Type` different than `application/json`.
Changing default `$http` options is not a variant, because a lot of queries still be performed with JSON data.

I've found example

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'example.com',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            data:  "somedata"
            }

 $http(req).then(function (resp) { console.log(resp);});
```

But it don't want to work — Content-Type is still a `application/json`.

Is any true way to do it right? Changing `$http` defaults and then restoring is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not a valid way to set headers in angularjs.

> To add or overwrite these defaults, simply add or remove a property
>   from these configuration objects. To add headers for an HTTP method
>   other than POST or PUT, simply add a new object with the lowercased
>   HTTP method name as the key, e.g. $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get =
>   { 'My-Header' : 'value' }.

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - "Setting HTTP Headers" section

Edit.

What you're doing is right but you're missing one thing.

In your scenario it does not work because when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you need to encode your data using `$httpParamSerializerJQLike()`. Also remember to put `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` as dependency.

Comment: But I need to set it only for one call, not for all.

Comment: Sorry, got mixed up when writing that answer. See edit.

Comment: Can you help with this question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314372/couchdb-sign-in-with-angularjs-auth-cookie-sent-for-session-only